# google visualization-Click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

I am using google visulaization for drawing pie chart.Issue i am facing is, **i cant able to capture click event** on pie chart.i am doing like this.

```
function drawchartfromRe()
{
    dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
            document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));
    //alert("RefuelLength"+totrefuelList.length);
    //alert("Vehicleid:"+totrefuelList[0].vehicleId);
   //google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
    data.addRows(totrefuelList.length);
    for (var i=0;i<totrefuelList.length;i++)
    {
       data.setValue(i, 0, totrefuelList[i].vehicleName);
       data.setValue(i, 1, totrefuelList[i].totalRefuelQty);
    }

    // var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
     chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
      'chartType': 'PieChart',
      'containerId': 'chart_div',
      'options': {
          title: 'Refuel Trend',
          height:'500',
          width:'400',
          backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' },
        'legend': 'right'
      }
    });

  /* google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function(e) {
       // var selection = chart.getSelection();
      var vehid= data.getValue(visualization.getSelection()[0].row, 0);
        getRefueldailywise(vehid);
    });*/
   // chart.draw(data, options);
   drawDashboard(dashboard,data,chart);
   google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
       // grab a few details before redirecting

      alert(data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row, 0));
       //location.href = 'http://www.google.com?row=' + row + '&col=' + col + '&year=' + year;
     });
}
```

In firebug i am getting error like this..
**dashboard.getChart is not a function**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chart Wrappers are not chart objects and do not have a `click` event. In fact, [Pie Charts also do not have a click event](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#Events), only `select`.

If you [read the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject) it says to:

1. Create a `ready` event for the wrapper
2. Have the `ready` event trigger a `select` event for the chart in the wrapper

Here is the example they give:

```
var wrapper;
function drawVisualization() {

  // Draw a column chart
  wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'ColumnChart',
    dataTable: [['Germany', 'USA', 'Brazil', 'Canada', 'France', 'RU'],
                [700, 300, 400, 500, 600, 800]],
    options: {'title': 'Countries'},
    containerId: 'visualization'
  });

  // Never called.
  google.visualization.events.addListener(wrapper, 'onmouseover', uselessHandler);

  // Must wait for the ready event in order to
  // request the chart and subscribe to 'onmouseover'.
  google.visualization.events.addListener(wrapper, 'ready', onReady);

  wrapper.draw();

  // Never called
  function uselessHandler() {
    alert("I am never called!");
  }

  function onReady() {
    google.visualization.events.addListener(wrapper.getChart(), 'onmouseover', usefulHandler);
  }

  // Called
  function usefulHandler() {
    alert("Mouseover event!");
  }
}
```

So in your case you will need to change this section:

```
   google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
       // grab a few details before redirecting

      alert(data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row, 0));
       //location.href = 'http://www.google.com?row=' + row + '&col=' + col + '&year=' + year;
     });
```

To something like this:

```
   google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function() {
       // grab a few details before redirecting
      google.visualization.events.addListener(chart.getChart(), 'select', function() {
          chartObject = chart.getChart();
          alert(data.getValue(chartObject.getSelection()[0].row, 0));
      });

       //location.href = 'http://www.google.com?row=' + row + '&col=' + col + '&year=' + year;
     });
```

Comment: in ur example also,there is one variable with name "chart".ie  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function()...here where u declared chart variable..actually in ur case there is only one variable.."wrapper"..can u pls explain

Comment: Sorry, I made a bunch of mistakes in my example at the bottom so I updated it. The point is that the wrapper is not a chart, it's a wrapper. `wrapperObject.getchart()` will return the chart object inside the wrapper. You need to set a listener on `chart.getChart()`, not on chart itself. (you may also want to change the name of the object from 'chart' to 'wrapper' to make your variables names also include that distinction)

Comment: when I try your example sir jmac, i'm getting error, `data is not defined`. I thought `data` is google visualization variable.

Comment: @Charles, mind asking a separate question with your code? If data is not defined, it could be for a variety of reasons, but likely not related to the event handler at all.

Comment: indeed jmac..i manage to trace the problem not totaly related to event..but instead my variable naming

Comment: @Charles, glad you could work it out! Good luck, and if you come across an issue, feel free to post it -- asgallant will likely be the one answering it as he's 50 times more knowledgeable than me, but you're in good hands with the google-visualization community in general.

Comment: @Sir jmac..while using your code on my barchart im recieving `undefined` output on this `alert(data.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row, 0));` I try replacing `row` with `column` and still no luck.

Comment: i'm trying to get the value of the highlighted bar. hopefully to sum them up so i can display the output on a `<span>` located on top of the chart..fyi: `isStacked = true`

Comment: @Charles, can I suggest [asking another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with all the relevant information included? (what code you're using, what problem you're getting, what you've tried to fix it, etc.) That's a lot easier than discussing through the comments.

Comment: this does not seem to work properly when you have a chart control wrapper on the chart. for example i have a line chart with a line chart filter (think stock chart with the draggable time range beneath the chart). when that range slider is utilized, it changes the row numbers in the original chart. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Following worked for me.

```
 chartEvents={[
    {
        eventName: "ready",
        callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
            const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
            const dataTable = chartWrapper.getDataTable();
            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "select", e => {
                if (chart.getSelection() && chart.getSelection()[0] && chart.getSelection()[0].row) {
                    const mydata = dataTable.getValue(chart.getSelection()[0].row, 0);
                    console.log(mydata);
                }
            });
        }
    }
]}
```

Comment: I think your if condition should be `if (chart.getSelection() && chart.getSelection()[0] ) {`, Otherwise it will not consider the `zeroth` item

Comment: If you mean that "&& chart.getSelection()[0].row" check is not needed, I think it won't cause harm, it simply checks if chart.getSelection()[0].row exists. Right ?

Comment: NO, it checks for the value in `row` which can be `zero` also in that whole condition fails.

Comment: You might be looking for this - `row in chart.getSelection()[0]`

Comment: Please check this > https://sl.bing.net/cQkGfINP6ia