# React google-charts callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I want to create an event handler for Chart component from [react-google-charts](https://github.com/RakanNimer/react-google-charts)

Off. documentation has an example.

```
<Chart
    chartType="ScatterChart"
    rows={this.state.rows}
    columns={this.state.columns}
    options={this.state.options}
    graph_id="ScatterChart"
    width="100%"
    height="400px"
    chartEvents={this.chartEvents} // <- this is event handler
   />
```

chartEvents looks like

```
this.chartEvents=[
  {
    eventName : 'select',
    callback  : function(Chart) {
        console.log("Selected ",Chart.chart.getSelection());
    }
  }
];
```

How can I refer to class context from the callback function? I want to change my local state.

```
this.chartEvents=[
  {
    eventName : 'select',
    callback  : function(Chart) {
        // here I want to refer to this.setState
        console.log("Selected ",Chart.chart.getSelection());
    }
  }
];
```

Comment: What error is raised if you attempt to setState in the callback?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same need as you and was able to do it. 
You can create a variable (superClass in the example below) and assign the value of the class (this) to it. This way you can still access it inside the scope of the callback.

```
const superClass = this;
this.chartEvents = [
  {
    eventName: 'select',
    callback(Chart) {
        // here you can refer to superClass.setState
        console.log("Selected ",Chart.chart.getSelection());
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: This _only_ works for the select event as per: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632698/google-visualization-click-event. Any Idea how do it for a click event?