# react-google-charts click event not working

Tags: reactjs, google-visualization

[According to the documentation](https://github.com/RakanNimer/react-google-charts#listen-to-chart-events), you can `Set the chart-specific events you want to listen to and the corresponding callback.` The example is given uses `select` which works fine (I've setup an example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nwxzo17vz4). The problem comes when I try to use *any* other chart type.

From the google charts documentation, for a [bar chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart), I should be able to use a click event:
[image: Screen Shot 2019-04-19 at 10 30 25 AM]

When I add a click event like so:

```
  {
    eventName: "click",
    callback({}) {
      console.log("clicked");
    }
  }
```

Nothing happens, but the select event still works. I've setup a code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/l9y2m671zq) to demonstrate this behavior. This also happens for [animationfinish](https://codesandbox.io/s/3128nzwqy5), [onmouseover](https://codesandbox.io/s/m5jm1lmryp), and every other event I've checked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [rakannimer](https://github.com/rakannimer) already answered this in [#263](https://github.com/rakannimer/react-google-charts/issues/263) on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/rakannimer/react-google-charts), but figured I'd answer this anyway in case anyone else was having this issue.

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15650043/1011803) stack overflow answer does a great job of explaining, the `ready` event must be fired before chart events (like those in the screenshot) can be triggered. Therefore, if you want to use any other event, you have to initiate them in a callback like [this](https://github.com/rakannimer/react-google-charts/issues/263#issuecomment-438155189):

```
<Chart
  chartType="ScatterChart"
  width="80%"
  height="400px"
  data={data}
  options={options}
  legendToggle
  chartEvents={[
    {
      eventName: "ready",
      callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
        const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "onmouseover", e => {
          const { row, column } = e;
          console.warn("MOUSE OVER ", { row, column });
        });
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "onmouseout", e => {
          const { row, column } = e;
          console.warn("MOUSE OUT ", { row, column });
        });
      }
    }
  ]}
/>
```

Comment: If there is a chance your chart will be 'ready' more than one time, be sure you avoid adding the mouse event listeners more than one time.

Comment: This is not working while adding click event. any suggestion?

Comment: @jakeSylvestre coud you please help me out on how I can attach click eb=vent to my horizontal labels https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629886/how-to-make-react-google-chart-label-clickable

Comment: Hey please help me out if you can

Answer (score 2):

Please check below code snippet for adding click event:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Chart } from "react-google-charts";

const chartEvents = [
      {
        callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
          const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
          chart.container.addEventListener("click", (ev) => console.log(ev))
        },
        eventName: "ready"
      }
    ];

const data = [
  ["age", "weight"],
  [8, 12],
  [4, 5.5],
  [11, 14],
  [4, 5],
  [3, 3.5],
  [6.5, 7]
];

const options = {
  title: "Age vs. Weight comparison",
  hAxis: { title: "Age", viewWindow: { min: 0, max: 15 } },
  vAxis: { title: "Weight", viewWindow: { min: 0, max: 15 } },
  legend: "none"
};
const ExampleChart = () => {
  return (
    <Chart
      chartType="ScatterChart"
      data={data}
      options={options}
      graphID="ScatterChart"
      width="100%"
      height="400px"
      chartEvents={chartEvents}
    />
  );
};

export default ExampleChart;
```

Comment: `chart.container` doesn't compile; there is no `container` on `chart` ; version "react-google-charts": "^4.0.0"

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the solution provided by @jake, the `chartWrapper` is no more available in the callback event. In my case, replacing it with `wrapper` works. Like

````
<Chart
  chartType="ScatterChart"
  width="80%"
  height="400px"
  data={data}
  options={options}
  legendToggle
  chartEvents={[
    {
      eventName: "ready",
      callback: ({ wrapper, google }) => {
        const chart = wrapper.getChart();
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "onmouseover", e => {
          const { row, column } = e;
          console.warn("MOUSE OVER ", { row, column });
        });
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "onmouseout", e => {
          const { row, column } = e;
          console.warn("MOUSE OUT ", { row, column });
        });
      }
    }
  ]}
/>```
````