# Using chartEvents on google-react-charts and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, charts, google-visualization, react-google-charts

I am having a react typescript project in which i am using `react-google-charts`. Based on reading a [similar discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632698/google-visualization-click-event/15650043#15650043) which works for JS, I am trying the same on Typescript.

I am having the below chart :

```
<Chart                    
        chartType="ColumnChart"
        width="80%"
        height="80%"
        data={data}
        options={options}
        chartEvents={[
            {
              eventName: "ready",
              callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
                const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
                google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "click", (e) => {
                  console.log("CLICK");
                });
              }
            }
          ]}
/>
```

Error I am getting is :

```
Argument of type '{ removeAction: (actionID: string) => void; getSelection: () => { row?: any; column?: any; }[]; setAction: (ChartAction: GoogleChartAction) => void; getImageURI: () => void; clearChart: () => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GoogleChartWrapper | GoogleChartControl | GoogleChartEditor'.
Type '{ removeAction: (actionID: string) => void; getSelection: () => { row?: any; column?: any; }[]; setAction: (ChartAction: GoogleChartAction) => void; getImageURI: () => void; clearChart: () => void; }' is missing the following properties from type 'GoogleChartWrapper': draw, toJSON, clone,
```

on the `google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "click", (e) => {` line.

**EDIT`** For a simpler version of the error you can check example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-fast-hrkby?file=/App.tsx)

I was expecting that the `addListener` called - will be the one under `google namespace` [to be called](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/google.visualization/index.d.ts#L1461). And other examples I've found on SO suggest that this should working, at least for React + JS. For example code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629886/how-to-make-react-google-chart-label-clickable).

But I cannot work the types correctly.

`chartEvents` are an array of [ReactGoogleChartEvent](https://github.com/rakannimer/react-google-charts/blob/master/src/types.ts#L532). Which means that the callback is defined [here](https://github.com/rakannimer/react-google-charts/blob/master/src/types.ts#L497). So google, is of type `GoogleViz`, and there is no `click` in the [GoogleVizEvents](https://github.com/rakannimer/react-google-charts/blob/master/src/types.ts#L224) and [GoogleVizEventName](https://github.com/rakannimer/react-google-charts/blob/master/src/types.ts#L214).

I don't know how all those examples that are posted are working.

What am I missing?

**Edit** Another example on the source repo of `react-google-charts` :
[Doesn't work for me still.](https://github.com/rakannimer/react-google-charts/issues/263)

**EDIT 2**

In essence, the issue is that the `getChart()` returns [this](https://github.com/rakannimer/react-google-charts/blob/master/src/types.ts#L188). I don't see how this can be used to create a listener for other properties like `onmouseover, click` etc as the above discussions are getting or solutions like[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55763605/react-google-charts-click-event-not-working/55763606).

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish by using the click event? from the code, it appears you're trying to get the row and column index from the data table, but the click event does not provide these properties. it only provides the id of the chart element that was clicked. if you use the select event, you can get row and column by using `chartWrapper.getChart().getSelection()` -- and you should be able to assign the select event in the same manner as the ready event.

Comment: That's some sample code - I've removed that. I need to update my state depending on some clicks on my chart. I'm confused on the types - seems I cannot make it work.

Comment: so looks like you would have to modify the react wrapper to include `"click"` as a valid `GoogleVizEventName`

Comment: Yes but that shouldn't be the case.  https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/google.visualization/index.d.ts#L1461 should take any string, but it seems the way I have it thinks that the interface is : https://github.com/rakannimer/react-google-charts/blob/master/src/types.ts#L225

Comment: the click event used in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57557639/5090771) from the last example you shared, uses a regular dom event, not a google click event.

Comment: Hmm code looks identical to me though - any guidance on what am I overseeing. Thanks a lot for the tips - I'll keep investigating.

Comment: in the answer I linked, the click events is assigned as --> `chart.container.addEventListener("click", ...` -- this is a regular dom event on the chart's `<div>` element -- the google click event is normally assigned as --> `google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, "click", ...`

Comment: point being, the regular dom event should work in the code you have, just not sure if it will work for what you need...

Comment: Interesting, I'll check again - `chart.container` doesn't work for me though as I still get that `container is not a property of chart`.

Comment: yes, I wondered about the container, never seen that, but the following should work --> `chartWrapper.getChart().getContainer()`

Comment: Btw this worked, so if you want to make it a proper asnwer I can confirm - or I can post my own answer to the above.

Answer (score 0):

The ts library is facing a type issue: https://github.com/rakannimer/react-google-charts/issues/545

```
  {
    eventName: "ready",
    callback: ({ chartWrapper, google }) => {
      const chart = chartWrapper.getChart();
      // the ts library is facing a type issue
      // https://github.com/rakannimer/react-google-charts/issues/545
      (google.visualization.events as any).addListener(
        chart,
        "onmouseover",
        (e: Event) => {
          console.log("onmouseover", e);
          drawCurrentTime(ref, currentTimeLabel)
        }
      );
    },
  };
```